# Safari сбрасывает cookies

Tags: cookie, safari

Други, такая проблема:

Есть сайт, на котором корзина реализована через cookies.
(Все предельно просто: в куку 'basket' пишется номер, с помощью которого из базы вытягивается то, что в корзине лежит.)
Во всех браузерах работает корректно. Safari же куку вообще не пишет.

Вроде удалось записать ее, с помощью js:

```
 Mage.Cookies.set('basket', t.id );
  location.reload();
```

После этого js релоада вроде как 1 раз подтягивает ее, но при переходе на другую страницу или обновлении она снова пропадает.

Кто нибудь с таким сталкивался? 
Можно ли как-то проблему решить или надо весь проект на сессии переводить?

Спасибо.

Comment: @volkoff, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой, решил не до конца.

1. заработали куки с нулевым временем жизни - session cookies, без указания `expires=`;
2. [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does) (на англ.) про проблему с установкой кук одновременно с 302 редиректом;
3. [спрашивают](http://toster.ru/q/22799) и [пишут](http://geektimes.ru/post/112077/) про проблему установки кук **внутри iframe** – т.е. со страниц, не открытых пользователем явно, по своей инициативе – для защиты от трекинга в iframe'ах.